# How to simply dump an SQS queue to s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, aws-cli

Preferably using the aws cli http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/receive-message.html. We have been trying to find some bash script or something that already exists that does this but no luck.

We don't need multi-threading/mapreduce/spark, our SQS queue is pretty tiny.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no specific functionality in the CLI to accomplish this. On the bright side, it would probably not be terribly difficult to implement this with one of the SDKs.